# Detecting dropped text in an input field?

Tags: javascript

I'm using dynamic labels that need to detect when input goes into a text input.

I detect keydown events and I also detect paste events, for when the user pastes in text.

However, I still do not detect text that is dragged and dropped in.

I looked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop) and it looks like I should detect drop events.

Is this correct.  Should I set an event listener for drop events?  How can I make sure it is text that is dropped and not something else?

Here is how I do my keypresses and pastes

```
input_element.addEventListener("paste", function () {
    label_element.style.opacity = 0;
}, false);
input_element.addEventListener("keypress", function () {
    label_element.style.opacity = 0;
}, false);
```

How do I detect drops of text?

One guess:

```
input_element.addEventListener("drop", function () {

    // verify it is text that is dropped

    label_element.style.opacity = 0;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Close:

```
input_element.addEventListener("dragdrop", function () {

// verify it is text that is dropped

    label_element.style.opacity = 0;
}, false);
```

Comment: You could run a check, `if (typeof dropString != 'string') { alert("not text"); }`

Comment: I believe `this.value` should return the text of whatever is being dragged. I could be wrong on that though.